# Error when editing wikimedia page in a protected namespace with api

Tags: namespaces, mediawiki, edit, protected, mediawiki-api

1. We have a mediawiki running.
2. We created a custom namespace ("NS_FOO").
3. We added a namespace (write) protection for "NS_FOO" (LocalSettings.php)
4. for all users except our custom user-group "QM".
5. We added pages to this custom namespace.

Everythings works just fine, i.e. no user can edit these pages except members of the group "QM".

6. We try to edit this page with the api (botpassword of a user who is member of the QM group)

We get the error:

```
code:"protectednamespace"
info:"You do not have permission to edit pages in the FOO namespace."
```

This is a part of the LocalSettings.php:

```
define("NS_FOO", 3000);
define("NS_FOO_TALK", 3001);

$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_FOO] = "foo";
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_FOO_TALK] = "foo_talk";

# add protection
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_foo] = ['QM-edit-rights'];

# Allow QM to edit "FOO" namespace
$wgGroupPermissions['QM']['QM-edit-rights'] = true;


$wgGroupPermissions['QM']['edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['QM']['createpage'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['QM']['delete'] = true;
etc.
```

I am aware of the fact that there are millions of things which can go wrong using the api. But in this case it only seems to depend on the protected namespace. Because:

1. The api edits work just fine, when changing pages in the default namespace. So there doesn't seem to be any problem changing pages with our api call in general.
2. On the other side, the edits in the protected namespace work fine when done personally and not using the api.

But the combination of editing a page in a protected namespace WITH the api creates the error quoted above.

My understanding of the bot password (or api access) is that it should inherit the group rights of the user. And if the user is allowed to edit a page the bot should also be able to do it (if not further restricted - which this bot password is NOT).

Does the bot password need some extra rights for protected namespaces?
Or are bots in general not able to change pages in protected namespaces?
Is this a mediawiki bug?

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding of the bot password (or api access) is that it should inherit the group rights of the user.

Bot password sessions inherit specific rights of the user. When managing the bot password, you have a list of rights bundles (grants), defined in [`$wgGrantPermissions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgGrantPermissions), and you can select which ones to inherit. If the relevant grant is not checked, or no grant is defined for that right in the first place, the bot password session will not have that right. (IOW, the bot will only have those rights for which it has both a userright and a grant.)

So, you'd need something like

```
$wgGrantPermissions['editpage']['QM-edit-rights'] = true;
```

in addition to the above.